# Issue with Firefox for list all file names in the current directory

Tags: javascript, filesystems

Searching all html files in that current directly and added in `div` tag with the hyper link..
Its works perfect in IE.. but it is not working in Firefox and Chrome .. any one can help me out....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCurrentDirectory() {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            path = unescape(document.location); 
            path = path.substring(8, path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1); 

            return path;
        }


        function ShowFolderFileList() {
            var fso, f, f1, fc, s, temp, Extention, fileName, temp2, filePath;
            folderspec = getCurrentDirectory();

            fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec);
            fc = new Enumerator(f.files);

            s = "";
            for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext()) {
                filePath = "" + fc.item() + "";
                fileName = fc.item().name;
                temp = "" + fileName + ""
                Extention = (temp.lastIndexOf(".") > -1) ? temp.slice(temp.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase() : "*";
                if (Extention == "html" || Extention == "htm") {
                    s += "<a href=\"" + fileName + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + temp.replace("." + Extention, "") + "</a> <br>";                                                            
                }

            }

            outPut.innerHTML = s;

        }
    </script>
```

In html

```
<div id="outPut">
</div>
```

anyone work on this....

Comment: ActiveXObject are objects available only on IE (and some of them can work under some circumstances, depending on the user security permission)

Answer (score 2):

[Firefox does not support ActiveX technology for multiple reasons.](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/ActiveX)

Same goes for Chrome.

If you really need file system access, something like [Java Web Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) would be an alternative.

Comment: Any alternate for this problem